# Find all positive integers $n$ such that $n^2$ divides $2^n+1$.

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $n$ such that $\dfrac{2^n+1}{n^2}$ is also an integer.

(IMO-$1990$)

Comment: n is not even because even number cant divide odd number

Comment: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asdas/imo/imo/isoln/isoln903.html

Comment: They're asking for integers, not primes.  $171$ divides $2^{171}+1$, for example.  The number $n$ can be a product of primes in $1$ and $3$ modulo $8$, as would its period.  The answers that i have seen in the url above and the previous question consider only primes, not composite integers.

Comment: @wendy.krieger But $171^2 \not\mid 2^{171}+1$, which is what the question is asking about. The solution posted to the duplicate is indeed correct for all $n$. It uses a prime factor of $n$, which is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @AlexBecker But it only handles base $2$, and some of the versions are seriously flawed and all are overly complex.  A general proof and construction is given for all $b$, including $10$.